# Subscribe to the same subscriber in rxJava 2

Tags: rx-java, observable, subscribe, rx-java2, reactive

In rxJava 1.x there was possible to do something like this:

```
Observable.<Foo>create(subscriber -> {
    ...
    getNewObservable().subscribe(Subscribers.wrap(subscriber));
})
```

GetNewObservable() returning also `Observable<Foo>`

I can't find the same approach in rxJava 2. There is no subscribe method accepting Emitter or ObservableEmitter on Observable object. I suppose I can do something like this:

```
Observable.<Foo>create((ObservableEmitter<Foo> emitter) -> {
    ...
    getNewObservable().subscribe(emitter::onNext, emitter::onError, emitter::onComplete);
})
```

But I'm wondering if there is some more straightforward way like in rxJava 1.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this unobvious approach? There must be much cleaner way of doing it. Please describe the purpose of your code.

Comment: Sure, there is probably more ways to workaround this, but I'm curious if there is really no equivalent in rxJava 2. This approach is in fact mentioned in [Reactive Programming with RxJava](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920042228.do) book.
But back to my case I'm doing android lib and I want to have observable witch will do some action every x minutes. So I have a timer observable for this. But the "work" requires some permissions to be granted. I just wanted to check permissions first and only if it's ok than subscribe to the timer observable. Otherwise return onError...

Comment: What about this: `if (permissionGranted) return Observable.interval(...).map(...); else return Observable.error(...);`?

Comment: Sure but i don't want to check the permissions on creation time but on subscription time. So only when the "wrapping" observable is subscribed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) One way of doing what you described in comments:

```
Observable.interval(...)
    .map(n -> {
            if (!permissionGranted)
                throw new AccessDeniedException();
            ... // do work
            return result;
        })
```

2) Another way of doing it:

```
Observable.interval(...)
    .flatMap(n -> {
            if (permissionGranted) {
                ... // do work
                return Observable.just(result);
            } else {
                return Observable.error(new AccessDeniedException());
            }
        })
```

3) Yet another way (check permission only once):

```
Observable.defer(() -> {
            if (permissionGranted) {
                return Observable.interval(...)
                    .map(n -> {
                        ... // do work
                        return result;
                    });
            } else {
                return Observable.error(new AccessDeniedException());
            }
        })
```

4) One more (the most *reactive*):

```
Completable.fromCallable(() -> {
            if (!permissionGranted)
                throw new AccessDeniedException();
            return true; // returned value does not matter
        })
    .andThen(Observable.interval(...)
                    .map(n -> {
                        ... // do work
                        return result;
                    })
        )
```

which you can refactor as:

```
askForPermission().andThen(getNewObservable())
```

Comment: Yes, checking the permission only once is sufficient for me so 3rd option is the best, but not really so elegant I was hoping for... So is there no equivalent in rxJava 2 as far as you know?

Comment: I've adjusted option 3 and added option 4. I think option 3 is the closest to your original intent, i.e. `defer` source selection until subscription time.